# twisted multiple messages reactor

Tags: python, twisted

I want to achieve this kind of functionality with twisted but I cant seem to get it:

Desired steps are:

1. make a connection to server

LOOP

```
1. wait until a special message 
2. send a message to server 
3. handle the responce (if it is a special message exit the loop and call reactor.stop())
```

END LOOP

I just cant achive simple functionality of sending data on demand with twisted. Instead it seems I have to know all the messages I want to send in advance.
Any solution to this?

Comment: If you want to send data "on demand", what is the demand to which you wish to respond?  In Twisted, any type of demand ought to be representable as an event – that is, a method call on some object you have previously hooked up.

Comment: demand being e.g. button of GUI pushed (not really but like it). The problem is that I just dont know how many times the button will get pushed. Meaning I dont know how many ".sendLine"s to use. I want to be able to invoke sendLine on demand. But it seems that twisted does reactor.run() # DO EVERYTHING AND NOTHING CAN BE ADDED DYNAMICALY reactor.stop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there's a solution, but what it is depends on exactly what your problem is. By which I mean: it's not clear why you think you have to know the messages you want to send in advance.

Twisted is a pretty classical async event-based, callback-controlled framework; everything is done "on demand" in response to some other event.

Comment: ok - let me explain it in more detail. It should be 
1. connect
2. leave the connection open...
3. "query the connection"
4. "query the connection few more times" (each time different message, but the same handler)
5. close the connection

=> I want to control this whole process outside of __main__ => e.g. when you click on a button I want to send a message. Close when you click another button and so on

Comment: That's all very doable; that's how Twisted is supposed to work. I'm not sure if by "query the connection" you mean "send a message and wait for a response" or "see if there is data available on the connection" or "see if the connection is closed", but it doesn't matter, you can do any of those.

Comment: ok I mean send a message and wait for a response - the problem for me is I dont know how many times I will send the message... Can you give me an example that connects, and allows me to send multtiple msgs without knowing the exact number... just creating them in a function? the example doesnt have to work... Just to give me an idea how to do that. My problem is that I feel I can only do reactor.run() #HAVE TO KNOW EVERYTHING BY NOW - Cant add any more msgs dynamicaly reactor.stop() => the thing is that I cant wait for all msgs to send. I have to make sure handler is called after each responce

Comment: reactor.run() just puts you in an event loop, meaning it waits for events you specify, and when they happen, it calls back into functions you specify. The events can be things like "when a connection is made", "when data is available on a connection", "when a timer goes off", "when a signal is received", etc. You can read many [examples](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/) and [tutorials](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) and [howtos](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html) to learn more.

Comment: yeah - my problem is on client side. What event to call when I want to  set a new msg? Should I construct the client factory again? I doubt it... 
I just want to 1. reactor.run() #HOW TO CREATE FIRST MSG, DYNAMICALY CREATE SECOND AND ALREADY ASYNCHRONOUSLY GET RESULTS FROM FIRST, SEND SECOND...